# DL185 G5 Upgrade to 3tb hard drives

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I would like to upgrade my DL185 G5 to take 3tb hard drives. the P400 controller does not support 3Tb hard drives. If I upgrade the controller to a P212 (which I already have), Do I simply use a SFF-8484 to SFF-8087 cable. Sorry I don't understand the backplane does it have it's own SAS expander built in.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the backplane has its own expander in *some* models. You did not specify which [HP ProLiant DL185 G5 model](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12864_div/12864_div.html) you have, though. How many drive bays does your unit have? That dictates the backplane setup. 12-bay units have a built-in expander, for instance.

I really wouldn't try to stuff newer drives into an old unit like that, given that the [DL180 G6 model](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13248_na/13248_na.HTML) is relatively affordable and more capable.

But using the right cables will work. You'll need the older SFF-8484 cables on the backplane side and the newer SFF-8087 on the controller side.

BTW - Do you have cache for your P212?